# What's the difference between "con brio" and "con fuoco"?

Tags: theory, technique, composition, terminology, tempo

Do they just have different names but are meant to be played the same?  Also, it seems like if "con fuoco" never appears in major keys, except for Beethoven's Piano Sonata No. 18.

Comment: I've asked a question on [meta] about retagging this question: [What is the proper tag name for tempo indications/directions/instructions?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3157/2257)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Brio' = vigour, spirit, fire.

'Fuoco' = fire, a combination of force and speed.

Both from Italian, meaning pretty well the same, one composer may use one, another the other. I doubt whether one would use both. No doubt someone will let us know!

Comment: I've seen "Allegro con brio" more often than "Presto con fuoco". "Allegro con fuoco" is even rarer, and then I don't think I've ever seen "Presto con brio".

Comment: "Presto con brio" - I've seen them.

Comment: "Brio" does not mean *fire,* except perhaps metaphorically.  I certainly see that meaning in no dictionary entry for the word.  "Fuoco," on the other hand, literally does mean *fire,* to the extent that Italian firefighters are the *vigili del fuoco.*

Comment: I am speaking of depicting a the literal concept of fire (i.e., paintings of fire are not literally aflame, yet they do depict literal fire) versus using a word that means "liveliness" and describing it as "fire."  Perhaps it is analogous to the difference between a dictionary and a thesaurus, where the latter will also include words that are related, but not necessarily synonyms.  Music that is "con fuoco" *should* evoke fire, but music that is "con brio" may or may not.

Comment: Not much to do with actual musical practice, but in Italian *brio* means *vivacity, merriment, exuberance*, not really *fire*

Comment: Although you are formally right, Tim, there is a little **theory** over character: "brio" is spirited like when you debate over the new president, while "fuoco" is like when you are desperate to use the restroom but it is locked.  In fact, "con fuoco" is more closely related to minor keys.

Answer (score 16):

**There’s not much (if any) difference in the tempo they imply, but there’s a difference in character.**

Literally, *con brio* means *with spirit*, while *con fuoco* means *with fire*.

Regarding tempo, both are traditionally taken to mean that it should be a little faster than it otherwise would be — *allegro con brio/fuoco* a bit faster than a typical *allegro*, and similarly for *presto con brio/fuoco*. There’s not much difference (in my experience) between the tempos they suggest; perhaps *con fuoco* tends to be taken as slightly faster than *con brio*, but there’s certainly a large overlap between the ranges they can cover.

In terms of character, though, there’s definitely a difference difference.  *Con brio* is more light-hearted, suggesting an enthusiastic, spirited kind of speed — fast because you’re enjoying going fast.  *Con fuoco* is more serious and urgent — going fast because there’s a fire at your heels, or a passion inside you that you can’t restrain.

Answer (score 5):

"Fuoco," meaning *fire,* implies heat and combustion, and therefore turbulence or, as [noted by guidot](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/80042/2257), urgency.  "Brio," meaning *liveliness* or *vigor,* does not.  This is consistent with your observation that the direction *con fuoco* is more closely associated with minor keys, which also tend to portray more complex or indeed turbulent emotions.

Comment: What direction does **this** situation fit to the best:  When you are desperate to pee but there are no restrooms available.

Answer (score 5):

Italian here, with a little background in music theory.
The words have very different meanings; especially the word "brio" I see being misinterpreted.

"Brio" means light-headed happiness. Think more of an elegant version of "allegro". I would play it by letting the fingers fly on the keyboard. (Note that allegro may also indicate how fast to play it: lentissimo < lento < allegro < presto < veloce < velocissimo)

"Fuoco" literally may mean fire, but in this case it is intended as "with passion". I would play it by smashing the notes, especially in long note and main passages.

While I'm here I also want to answer some comments:
"Allegro con brio" means happy, but the brio part focuses on the distracted nature of happiness, like you are casually playing the music just because you like it.

"Presto con fuoco" means fast with passion; like you are going to your crush and she is home alone.

"Allegro con fuoco" means happy with passion; like your crush told you to come over tomorrow as she will be home alone.

Comment: "Note that allegro may also indicate how fast to play it": many native speakers of English are probably unaware that allegro can mean anything other than an indication of speed.

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat misleading, that both may be translated to *with fire*.

If I remember correctly *con brio* mostly means lively. Its mostly used to supplement *Allegro* to give a sort of tempo indication, see [related question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/78312/2600).

*Con fuoco* is the real *with fire*, meaning a sort of urgency, as if the coat were on fire. Summarized: *Con brio* is considerably more harmless, which as Dekkadeci comments, makes it a useless addition to *Presto*.

Comment: Does this mean that "con fuoco" is NEVER used in major keys, but only in minor keys?

Comment: @RailroadHill: While my first example, Dvroaks symphony #9, 4th movement is in e minor, I don't recognize, why speed should strictly map to major or minor.

Comment: Do you have any support to the assertion that "brio" may be translated as "fire"?  I do not see that sense in any dictionary, so to the extent that it may be translated thus, it is metaphorical.

Comment: WHen I see "brio," I think toy train sets :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I only think Hornby double O, or Triang. Please explain!

Comment: @Tim For example [Article from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brio_(company)) - it's a swedish wood toy company which is best known for their wooden toy trains.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - well, that pretty well proves that 'brio' won't mean 'fire'..! Unless they were steam trains?

Answer (score 1):

Con Fuoco would be hard, fast and loud. Con Brio would be with spirit but this can be at a relaxed tempo as well, Con Brio, spirited like when you debate something that is very important to you, Con Fuoco, losing your temper at someone who has madden you to the point you want to slap him.

Comment: Beethoven's Symphony 5 1st mvt, in C minor, is marked "Allegro con **brio**", while it is very raging and stormy.

Comment: Beethoven Piano sonata No.18 in E flat major, fourth movement